# How to count nonblank values in each dataframe row

Tags: r, pandas

Given a data frame in R how do I determine the number of non blank values per row.

```
col1 col2 col3 rowCounts
1     3        2
      1    6   2
           1   1
               0
```

This is how I did it in python:

```
df['rowCounts'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.count(), axis=1)
```

What is the R Code for this?

Comment: I think you can avoid the `apply` : `df.notna(1).sum(1)` , similar to akrun's answer on rowsums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use (assuming `NA` as blank) `rowSums` as a vectorized option on the logical matrix (`!is.na(df)`) where TRUE (`->1` i.e. non-NA) values will be added for each row with `rowSums`

```
df$rowCounts <- rowSums(!is.na(df))
```

-output

```
df
#   col1 col2 col3 rowCounts
#1    1    3   NA         2
#2   NA    1    6         2
#3   NA   NA    1         1
#4   NA   NA   NA         0
```

If the blank is `""`

```
df$rowCounts <- rowSums(df != "", na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1` as a similar syntax to Python (though it will be slower compared to `rowSums`)

```
df$rowCounts <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, NA, NA, NA), col2 = c(3L, 1L, NA, 
NA), col3 = c(NA, 6L, 1L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```